# Inflate zip stream with Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a zip stream inside a BLOB field in the database. I'm trying to inflate it but have been so far unable.

The problem is that this stream is a zipped stream, not a complete zip file.

In case it makes it clearear, this would be the Java code to inflate it:

```
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(fis2);
FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(args[2]);

doCopy(iis, fos2);
```

I want to be able to do this in Oracle PL/SQL instead of Java. Is it possible or I should create a Java procedure in the database?

Thanks and regards

Comment: why not use java if you already know how to ?

Comment: It's just that I'm trying to avoid the overhead of using Java and needing to install it on the server.
Besides, the system administrator won't approve this so easily

Answer (score 0):

There is the UTL_COMPRESS package but I don't think it'll help you.
I'd use Java stored procedure ....

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but as the stream is not a complete file UTL_COMPRESS would not recognize it.
Perhaps if I could create a file around it...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
It seems like there is a function in the UTL_COMPRESS library that can inflate the stream byte by byte. The only missing piece is to calculate a checksum and add it to the end of the data.

This is the link where I found it and with sample source code:
http://technology.amis.nl/blog/7626/utl_compress-gzip-and-zlib

Comment: Thanks for updating, im sure it will come in handy in the future